# Как запустить контейнер docker nginx c параметром максимального размера загружаемого файла

Tags: nginx, docker

Запускаю контейнер nginx
мне нужно указать  client_max_body_size 5g;
не пойму что-то как дописать. Подскажите

```
docker run -d --restart=always -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеется ввиду, что  `client_max_body_size 5g;` надо добавить в конфигурацию nginx'а, а не в конфигурацию запуска контейнера nginx через docker. Согласно секции **Proxy-wide** [документации docker-образа jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) дополнительные настройки можно подсунуть, закинув дополнительный файл в `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` с расширением `*.conf`. Итого, создаётся файл `my_conf.conf` с таким содержимым:

```
client_max_body_size 5m;
```

После это можно запускать командой

```bsh
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v $(pwd)/my_conf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_conf.conf:ro -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

P.S. обрати внимание, что `$(pwd)/my_conf.conf` - это относительный путь, потому в таком виде запускать надо из той же директории, где лежит `my_conf.conf`